# Sending data for conditional check across Chronoform V5 multipage form for Joomla CMS

Tags: joomla3.0, chronoforms

I am using Chronoform V5 for my Joomla site. I have created a Multi Page form wherein a user will fill in each page and click next to proceed and at the end the form will be finally submitted and some results will be displayed based on the input. This part works fine.

Now I have a dropdown in first page. If a user selects e.g, option 'a' and clicks 'next page' button i want to hide a dropdown in the second page. In case the user selects option 'b' in the first page this dropdown in second page should be visible.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Custom code action to check the submitted value and use CSS to show or hide the value:

```
<?php
$display = 'block';
if ( $form->data['var_name'] == 'xxx' ) {
  $display = 'none';
}
$style = "#some_id { display: '{$display}'; }";
$jdoc = \JFactory::getDocument();
$jdoc->addStyleDeclaration($style);
?>
```

Comment: Thank You GreyHead.